# ASP.Net / C# Dynamically Generated Radio Buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I'm writing a small app for SharePoint and I want to check the number of workflows in a library and add them to a table with 3 options for each - terminate, start, and restart.

How can I dynamically generate n number of terminate, start, and restart radio button groups (n being # of workflows in the library) so that I can iterate through each group to see which functionality is selected for each workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `OnInit` method of your control add code like this (has to be executed every time, even on postbacks)

```
protected override OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        var chk = new CheckBox();
        chk.CheckedChanged += this.CheckBoxChanged;
        chk.Text = "CHK#" + i.ToString();
        chk.ID = "chk_" + i.ToString();

        this.Controls.Add(chk);
    }
}

protected void CheckBoxChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var chk = (CheckBox)sender;
    var i = int.Parse(chk.ID.SubString(4));
    // "i" now holds the number of the checkbox changed.
}
```

The events and properties will change for different controls but the overall mechanism will not.